# Server time-out during save\deploy in Eclipse

Tags: deployment

I have continuously gotten server time-out errors ("waiting for a response from server...." etc. ) when deploying to Production from Eclipse. However, after I get the error and then go into Production the changes are there. Has anybody ever experienced this before ? The code I am attempting to deploy does not require a test (new field ; new layout). I've also gotten it when I try to save to Production from Eclipse.

Has anybody else experienced this ? Even though the changes appear once I go back into Production it still gives me an uneasy feeling, making me wonder if I will be experiencing errors down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system (salesforce.com) requires a RunAllTest when deploying metadata to production, even if no code changes. The status updates provided are initiated by the Eclipse IDE, not a long-poll on the server. In other words, Eclipse keeps asking "are you done yet?" every few seconds for a window of time (somewhere in the neighborhood of 5 minutes), and if the server isn't done by then, it stops asking. If you have a lot of test code in production, this is a fairly normal scenario. You can check the deployment status in Setup > Deploy > Monitor Deployments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response sfdcfox. This is actually related to the question you helped me with yesterday regarding cloning an object in Eclipse. I ended up using the method I showed in my last response and it all seemed fine (no Problems). I figured it had to do with the testing since I didn't get the same response when deploying the new object to a sandbox. I checked the deployment log like you suggested and it was "Completed with Errors", which was kinda what I expected since the object showed up full but the deployment timed-out.

Comment: ftr - it just completed successfully for me. Just thought I'd let you know. Thanks again sfdcfox !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the time, one client routinely takes 45 minutes to run all tests.  For that reason I generally don't use Eclipse for deployments since it's completely locked up until things complete.

Regardless of Eclipse locking up, you're deployment will go through.  The downside is you may never get the results.

Using change sets avoids the issue entirely, and if you're into XML, the Force.com Migration Tool (aka ANT with a salesforce library) with a little tweaking will keep polling for even the longest deployments.